# Element not moving on resizing page

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am placing a heading/title on a HTML page using following code:

```
<table width="100%" height="55px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
         <td style="height:10px">&nbsp;
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:105px;"></td>
        <td align="left"  style="padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px">

        <div style="font-family:quicksand;font-size: 28px; color:##bdbdc0;z-         index:1000000;position:relative;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            De Graef    <font size="2">Landelijk & Sfeervol Wonen</font>
        </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Other content is in other tables.

When i zoom in or zoom out, or simply change resolution, this text is not moving it's position in sync with the other page elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should recreate it in jsFiddle.net, it will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Validate your code - half of that is deprecated- table has no colspan, syntax has many errors.

Comment: please check out the page http://www.antiek.net/degraef/new2/

Answer (score 1):

Change your header row to this :

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:quicksand;font-size: 28px; color:##bdbdc0;margin-left:-50px;background-color:##4D4946;">
        <table width="956" border="0" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:##4D4946;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:##4D4946;">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <img style="background-color:##4D4946;" src="images/logonew.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm helping you here but should seriously consider rewriting **all of it** in a clean and modern way, most of your code is **deprecated** :

- Use appropriate HTML markup for segmenting your document
- Use `<table>` **only** when then you need an actual table
- Use separate CSS files for keeping your markup clean
- [Read](http://www.w3schools.com/) the W3C recommendations about all of this